# $http in Anjgularjs: Can someone explain the flow

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

In an $http call, What all things we can pass in the url part, I have a server address, a user name and Password. Can i pass all as a json object?, or we have any other parameter (like url) for this.?
Can someone help me in understanding what is happening on a success call.

Specifically, the code I'm struggling with is:

```
app.factory('myFactory',function(){

var fact = {};
fact.getData = function(a){
    $http({method:'POST',url:'http://100.100.100.100:8080/xx/xx.xx'});
    $http.success(function(reply){a(reply)}
        );
};

return fact;
```

});

---

See the following code, still I am not getting data from server, at the same time no errors too.

```
xapp.factory('loginData',function($http,$log){
    var fact = {};

    fact.getData = function(cred,cb){
        return
            $http({
                method:'post',
                url:'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/xxxxxx',
                data:cred})
            .success(function(data,status,header,config){
                cb(data);
                })
            .error(function(data,status,header,config){
                $log.warn(status);
                });
    };

    return fact;
});


xapp.controller('mainController',function($scope,$log,$http,loginData){
    $scope.user = {uesr:'user',password:'123'};

    loginData.getData($scope.user,function(data){
        $scope.reply = data;
        });
});
```

In the console log, I get an 'undefined'. If the http url is correct, do u see any issue?

Comment: $http.success(function(reply){a(reply)});

Here, how is reply working, it is a parameter in both the functions????

Comment: The full callback function signature for the `success` method is: `function(data, status, headers, config)`. "reply" as per your question corresponds to the response body of your HTTP request.

Comment: So let me rewrite it as 
$http.success(function(data,status,header,config){
a(reply)
});

How do we use this a() here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, `a` parameter is a callback function that is executed when reply from server is received. This kills the purpose of promises that the `$q` service provides. Also, `$http` service itself does not have `.success` callback. It returns a `promise` object with `.success` and `.error` callbacks. Here's how it should be done:

```
app.factory('myFactory', function() {
  var fact = {};
  fact.getData = function() {
    return $http.get('your/path/to/resource/');
  }
  return fact;
})
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, myFactory) {
  myFactory.getData().then(function(response){
    //response.data holds your data from server
  }, function(){
    //this fn gets called when error happens
  });
});
```

Some explanations: `myFactory.getData()` creates a new http request to the server and returns a promise object which has a method `.then(successCallback, errorCallback)`. You can provide callbacks to the promise to be executed after request is complete.

You might get confused with my mentioned `.then(successCallback, errorCallback)` and `.success(callback)` used in your example. A generic `promise` that `$q` provides has `.then` method, but `$http` service, upon returning a promise, provides shortcuts `.success()` and `.error()` but it's the same thing in the end.

Comment: One more thing, If it was a **post** operation instead of get, how would we write it?. Consider we need to pass a json object to the factory.
Thanks for your Reply.

Comment: `$http` documentation is here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http. Are you sure you need **POST** request to __get__ some data?

Comment: In the above code, can the factory be rewritten as

app.factory('myFactory', function() {
  var fact = {};
  fact.getData = function() {
    return $http({method:'GET',url:'your/path/to/resource/'});
  }
  return fact;
})

Comment: Yes, you can rewrite it like that.

Comment: For **post** with json, you can use this snippet: `$http({method:'POST', url: 'url', data: yourJsonObject})`

Comment: In the below reply by Danish, in the function fact.getData, no **return** is used, did that matter?

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem of sending body.

```
  app.factory('myFactory', function($http) {
    return{
       getData : function(body) {
        return $http({
          url: 'http://100.100.100.100:8080/xx/xx.xx',
          method: 'POST',
          data:body
        })
      }
   }
 });


 app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $location, $http, myFactory){

    var body ={username:uname, password:pass};
    myFactory.getData(body).success(function(data){
       $scope.data=data;
    });
 });
```